# Summarize PySpark data frame with first non-null value for each ID for all columns

Tags: r, pyspark

I have a PySpark data frame with the following structure but with many more rows and columns.

| id | col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | null | null |
| 1 | null | B | null |
| 1 | null | null | C |
| 2 | D | null | null |
| 2 | null | E | null |
| 2 | null | null | F |

I want to summarize the data frame by selecting the first non-null value for each ID for all the columns.

The result I need:

| id | col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | B | C |
| 2 | D | E | F |

I can do this in R with dplyr using the below code:

```
df %>% group_by(id) %>% summarize_all(list(~first(na.omit(.))))
```

Is there a way to do this in PySpark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df = (
    df
    .groupBy('id')
    .agg(*[f.first(f.col(column), ignorenulls= True).alias(column) for column in df.columns if column != 'id'])
)
```